# Unable to create a WiX xml definition using XDocument because it cant create the illegal element ;`<?include .. ?/>`

Tags: xml, wix, linq-to-xml

I want to programaticly create the folowing xml structure

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <?include "mypath\Constants.wxi"?>
    <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.ProductName)" Language="$(var.ProductLanguage)" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.ProductManufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer vesrion of [ProductName] is already installed" />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
        <MediaTemplate />
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

i tried using XDocument

```
  XDocument xmldoc = new XDocument(
        new XElement("Wix",
            new XText("<?include \"" + constantfileloc + "\"?>"),
            new XElement("Product",
              new XAttribute("Id", "*"),
              new XAttribute("Name", "$(var.ProductName)"),
              new XAttribute("Language", "$(var.ProductLanguage)"),
              new XAttribute("Version", "$(var.ProductVersion)"),
              new XAttribute("Manufacturer", "$(var.ProductManufacturer)"),
              new XAttribute("UpgradeCode", "$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)"),
              new XElement("Package",
                  new XAttribute("InstallerVersion", "200"),
                  new XAttribute("Compressed", "yes"),
                  new XAttribute("InstallScope", "perMachine")
              ),
              new XElement("MajorUpgrade",
                    new XAttribute("DowngradeErrorMessage", "A newer vesrion of [ProductName] is already installed")
              ),
              new XElement("UIRef",
                  new XAttribute("Id", "WixUI_Minimal")
              ),
              new XElement("MediaTemplate")
           )
        )
  );
```

the problem is ofcourse the `<?include?/>` which can't be created by `XElement` because it does not allow an element to start with a ?
So i thought i could make it work by using `XText` but apperently its replacing my `<` and `>` in the `XText` declaration for `&lt` and `&gt`.

i also tried using `XElement.parse("<?include \"" + constantfileloc + "\"?>")`
but i can't get it to work,

is it posible using XDocument? because i realy don't want to use a textwriter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. What you're seeing are not text sections. They're processing instructions. You have to use XProcessingInstruction instead of XText. Check out [the documentation on the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xprocessinginstruction.aspx). You can use it similarly to the following :

```
XDocument xmldoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Wix",
        new XProcessingInstruction("include", constantfileloc),
        new XElement("Product",
          new XAttribute("Id", "*"),
          new XAttribute("Name", "$(var.ProductName)"),
          new XAttribute("Language", "$(var.ProductLanguage)"),
          new XAttribute("Version", "$(var.ProductVersion)"),
          new XAttribute("Manufacturer", "$(var.ProductManufacturer)"),
          new XAttribute("UpgradeCode", "$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)"),
          new XElement("Package",
              new XAttribute("InstallerVersion", "200"),
              new XAttribute("Compressed", "yes"),
              new XAttribute("InstallScope", "perMachine")
          ),
          new XElement("MajorUpgrade",
                new XAttribute("DowngradeErrorMessage", "A newer vesrion of [ProductName] is already installed")
          ),
          new XElement("UIRef",
              new XAttribute("Id", "WixUI_Minimal")
          ),
          new XElement("MediaTemplate")
       )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried most X... types but overlooked the `XProcessingInstruction`.